# iOS - cannot interact with video shared directly to instagram story

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram, instagram-graph-api, instagram-story

I'm working on an instagram share feature on both Android and iOS, and I've noticed sub-par behavior on iOS. I've tried using both the `@"instagram://library?AssetPath="` API, as well as the [official graph calls](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories), and I cannot find a way to add a video file as a "sticker".

Using `@"instagram://library?AssetPath="`:

- Android shares the video as an adjustable sticker and creates new story slots per the length of the video shared. For example, if I share a minute long video, I am able to pinch zoom and rotate it, and I can see it spanning across 3 story panels.
- iOS shares the video (seemingly) as a "backgroundVideo" ([see `com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundVideo`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories)). This is static, and set to fill the screen by height. I cannot interact with this video at all, and it is cropped at 20 seconds in length to fill only one single story panel.

The same video file, when added to a story directly from the Instagram app, works correctly as a sticker and looks immensely better.

I also may be totally wrong here, but I'm mostly confident that about 5 weeks ago, iOS was not behaving this way using the `@"instagram://library?AssetPath="` method. Perhaps this api was altered.

Has anyone experienced this before? Anyone have ideas on how to share a video file directly and be able to adjust it?

Comment: do you have read the ios13 changelog? maybe there is update on the video editing behaviour